# Migrate Ubuntu VM from VirtualBox to VMWare, lost internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware

I have a Ubuntu (18) VM that I did a minimal install. I used it for a while in VirtualBox and everything works, network interface came up on its own. Then I decided I need to migrate to VMWare Player. So I had the VM shutdown, exported the VM into an .ova, closed VirtualBox and import it from VMWare Player.

VM came up pretty fast but I realized the only network interface (ens33) is down

`2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000`

If I manually `sudo ip link set ens33 up` and run dhclient, it will come up and get an IP, until next reboot. I suppose I can put it in an init script to come up automatically.

Both VirtualBox and VMWare's interface setting is NAT. But I am wondering why it didn't come up on its own? What did the VM migration do that cause the interface to not come up?

Is there a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting and reading countless posts about editing `/etc/network/interfaces` which does not work for me. I came across a post mentioning about netplan.

There is a `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file in my ubuntu. Inside, it lists an interface named `enp0s3`, I am not sure what it is for as I only added 1 ethernet interface and it shows up as `ens33`. So I added a couple of lines:

```
ens33:
  dhcp4: yes
```

Executing `sudo netplan apply` brings the interface up right away. Reboot also works fine.